# WP 8.1 ListView item, ist's events and size manipulation in 'real-time'

Tags: listview, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

My goal is to make a list with items, where every from them is little bit interactive. So every item:

- Change it's height with animation when tapped
- Fire event when tapped in heart icon

It's nothing hard sure? No it's not, cause when I fire `Animation.Begin()` to start animate height of item, animation working fine, but when I scroll down the list, there are items that aren't tapped but are "enlarged" by animation. It looks like recycle view do something strange with "new loaded" items or event is somehow shared between different elements of ListView. I have no idea how to fix it, I've searching a lot, but with no result, anyone of you found a solution to that?

**EDIT:**

**Solution in comments to first answer.**

Answer (score 0):

Try by setting   `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode` attached property on listview . See the details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 <ListView VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"></ListView>
```

Comment: It doesn't help, by default `VirtualizationMode` in `ListView` is `Standard` so passing it explictly don't change anything (I tried it anyway). Second thing I tried was give `DataContext` additional property called `IsExpanded` and checking it every time item is loaded in UI, same bad result as before.

Comment: I probably solved the problem, `ListView` with `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"` should create new instance of item everytime when it disapear from screen and come back, but unfortunelly situation is little bit different and similiar to `Recycle` mode. Item containers always are the same, but `DataContext` is changing, so I listen on event `DataContextChanged` inside `UserControl` and set valid state of item inside control code behind.